# ∂/∂ and ∂/∂, are they elements of a Ring or a Vector Space??

Tags: complex-analysis, ring-theory, vector-spaces

As we know, in complex analysis we can define
$${\partial _z} = {1 \over 2} ({\partial _x} + {1 \over i}{\partial _y}) \ \text{and}\ {\partial _\overline{z}} = {1 \over 2} ({\partial _x} - {1 \over i}{\partial _y})$$
Well, it looks like $\partial _x,\ \partial _y$ satisfy the axioms of both Ring and Vectors Space, can someone tell me if I'm wrong? If this is right, what kind of Ring and Vector Space do they sit in? Any particularly interesting properties in them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They live inside a structure which is both a ring and a vector space in a compatible way, called an [associative algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_algebra) (compatibility means multiplication is bilinear). This algebra is called the algebra of [differential operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_operator), and various spaces of smooth functions are naturally [modules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_(mathematics)) over it. There are lots of different versions of this construction; the simplest one, which gives the differential operators with polynomial coefficients, is the [Weyl algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_algebra). There's a lot more to say about this but it depends on what you want to know and what you're trying to do.

Comment: Awesome,  very exciting to find out this question is so rewarding! Thanks a lot for the links, I'll look into them.